# What group is Paul referring to in Colossians 2:18?

Tags: colossians

> ”Let no one disqualify you, insisting on asceticism and worship of angels, going on in detail about visions, puffed up without reason by his sensuous mind,“
> *‭‭Colossians‬ ‭2‬:‭18‬ ‭ESV‬‬*

Is there a specific group Paul is mentioning here? I’m unaware of a  Jewish group that “worshiped angels”.

Comment: Straightforward question to identify a referent seems to belong to BH.SE.  If you have more than that in mind, something that C.SE is better equipped to answer, please include it in the question.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Yea I don’t disagree this could be transferred, but it’s also a question that deals with historical theology and stuff so it (probably) could be left here

Comment: The identification of a group being Jewish or gentile will be speculative.

Comment: @Michael16 the context of the passage is judaisers… so no it won’t be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worship of angels was an ongoing issue in Phrygia (part of modern-day Turkey, where Colossae is located), for a number of centuries. It appears to have begun in Judaism and spread to Christianity, and it was one of the topics addressed in the 4th-century Council of Laodicea.

Paul appears to be guarding against this known influence in this part of the world.

The following commentaries provide helpful context:

**Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary**

> Under pretext of humility, as if they durst not come directly to God and Christ ...they invoked angels: as Judaizers, they justified this on the ground that the law was given by angels. This error continued long in Phrygia (where Colosse and Laodicea were), so that the Council of Laodicea (A.D. 360) expressly framed its thirty-fifth canon against the "Angelici" (as Augustine [Heresies, 39], calls them) or "invokers of angels." Even as late as Theodoret's time, there were oratories to Michael the archangel.

**Benson's commentary**

> It evidently appears, from several passages in Philo, to have been the opinion of that learned Jew, that angels were messengers who presented our prayers to God, as well as brought down his favours to us. He represents this view of the matter as most humble and reverential, and there is no doubt but it prevailed among other Jews. See Tob 11:14; Tob 12:12; Tob 12:15. It was undoubtedly because the Jews entertained so great a respect for angels, on account of their supposed agency in human affairs, that the apostle, in this epistle, and in that to the Hebrews, took so much pains to show that the Son of God is greater than all angels.

This "group" could be referred to as the "Angelici", but this is Augustine's term for them, not a term contemporary to Paul.